# PIP: "Fatal error in launcher" when trying to download scipy

Tags: python, scipy, pip

#### THE PROBLEM

After failing to download scipy due to some error, I've tried installing and uninstalling python, downgrading to python3.75 and back to python 3.8 - now nothing works.

That is, typing `pip` in the command line returns the following error:

`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\alon\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\alon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" '`

All I want to do is to get scipy working, but now everything is broken.

#### WHAT I'VE TRIED

I literally went over all threads in SO and other places that deal with this error, but nothing has worked.

I tried deleting python and downloading it again, but the problem still exists.

#### OTHER DETAILS

I'm working on `Windows 10`.

#### EDIT

After trying to delete everything and reinstalling, I'm getting this when executing `pip` in the cmd line:

````
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined```


When I execute ```echo %PATH%``` this is what I get:

```C:\Program Files\Cmder\bin;C:\Program Files\Cmder\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Program Files\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\alon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Cmder```


While when I enter "edit environment variables" this is what appears under ```path```:

```C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;```

Which is a completely different list.
````

Comment: You probably have to install pip manually, but for a quick solution you might try to unistall python, then delete ALL the related remaining files and directories in `C:\Users\alon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` (backup any script you have saved there, if needed) and finally install it again. It should work just fine now.

Comment: did it, now when I try ```pip``` it says ```'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.```
This happens even though I have python/Scripts in the path.

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure it's been added to the Path environment variable?

Comment: When I execute ```echo %PATH``` this is what I get:

Comment: I don't happen to see the correct python path in the list. Try executing `setx PATH “%PATH%;C:\Users\alon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts"`

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problems. I also have windows 10. After pip install and pip3 install worked originally and then stupped working (beats me)

```
py -m pip install whatver-it-is-your-trying-to-install
```

worked for me.